# what's the difference between rm -rf and rm -r?

Tags: linux, command, rm

In linux, what is the difference between 'rm -rf' and 'rm -r', both seem to do the same things (delete an entire directory).

Here is a few commands that I ran to test it:

```
mohammad@mohammad-ThinkPad-E570:~/testerr$ ls
mohammad@mohammad-ThinkPad-E570:~/testerr$ mkdir foo1 foo2
mohammad@mohammad-ThinkPad-E570:~/testerr$ touch foo1/main.java foo2/main.java
mohammad@mohammad-ThinkPad-E570:~/testerr$ tree
.
├── foo1
│   └── main.java
└── foo2
    └── main.java

2 directories, 2 files
mohammad@mohammad-ThinkPad-E570:~/testerr$ rm -r foo1
mohammad@mohammad-ThinkPad-E570:~/testerr$ ls
foo2
mohammad@mohammad-ThinkPad-E570:~/testerr$ rm -rf foo2
mohammad@mohammad-ThinkPad-E570:~/testerr$ tree
.

0 directories, 0 files
mohammad@mohammad-ThinkPad-E570:~/testerr$
```

Comment: What did you learn when you checked `man rm` ?

Comment: https://ss64.com/bash/rm.html

Comment: Try `chmod a-w foo1/main.java` before the `rm -r` or `rm -rf` commands and you're likely to see the main difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`-f` option is there to remove the prompts.

`-r` option is there to work recursively.

Let's say that we have a folder named `stackoverflow` with the contents of `image.jpg otherimage.jpg mydog.doc`

Upon typing `rm -r stackoverflow` terminal may say: `rm: descend into write-protected directory 'stackoverflow'?` and if you say `y` it will ask you for new questions.

```
rm: remove write-protected regular file stackoverflow/image.jpg'?
rm: remove write-protected regular file stackoverflow/otherimage.jpg'?
rm: remove write-protected regular file stackoverflow/mydog.doc'?
```

Basically, it will ask every step if you want to do this operation or not.

Now let's try with `rm -rf stackoverflow`

No questions will be asked this time and, all the content inside the folder is now deleted.

Answer (score 1):

`rm -rf` ignores non-existent files, and never prompt before removing.

`rm -r` removes directories and their contents recursively.
https://www.computerhope.com/unix/urm.htm